# Context not in sync

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component that is using Context like so:

```
export const MyContext = React.createContext({});

export const MyComponent = React.memo(({children}) => {
  const [myVar, setMyVar] = React.useState({});

  const myFunction = () => {
    console.log(myVar);
    setMyVar({...myVar, {extraData: 'hi there'}});
  };

  const updateMyVar = React.useCallback((data) => {
    setMyVar(data);
  }, []);

  const doSomethingElse = React.useCallback(() => {
    myFunction();
  }, []);

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={{myVar, updateMyVar, doSomethingElse}}>{children}</MyContext.Provider>
  );
});
```

And then using it in a component:

```
const {myVar, updateMyVar, doSomethingElse} = React.useContext(FormContext);
```

The child component can seem to update `myVar` just fine, but inside of the `MyComponent` component, when I try to read `myVar` in something like the `myFunction` function just returns whatever the state was initially initialized with. It never updates to show the data that is there currently. The funny thing is that the child component always reads the correct data.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no code sandbox linked to the question, I can only take a guess. I think your `myFunction` will be stale if it is called within `doSomethingElse`  as the dependencies are stale.

Can you try this ?

```
  const doSomethingElse = React.useCallback(() => {
    myFunction();
  }, [myFunction]);
```

If you don't want to do that, another way would be to do this. Here you are accessing the current value of the state using the callback variant of state setter function. Let me know if this helps.

```
 const myFunction = () => {
    console.log(myVar);
    setMyVar(currentMyVar => {... currentMyVar, {extraData: 'hi there'}});
  };
```

Comment: I think you're leading me down the right track. My real code is a bit more complex so it's hard to make an example out of, but I do think you're right about it being stale. I tried your example and it doesn't fix it, but I'll keep trying. I've tried moving the `doSomethingElse` function into both `useCallback` and `useRef` but that doesn't seem to fix the issue either.

Comment: I might be able to find the solution if you can share a code sandbox link.